# How to update classic field service Apps to Lightning

Tags: lightning

Is there a new managed package that needs to be installed to receive the Lightning version of the Field Service Apps?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - I have the latest version of that package, and the packaged apps are still Classic. They work in Lightning, of course, but if you want full Lightning (or Lightning Console) apps with a Utility Bar, end-user customizability, etc, you'll need to create new Lightning apps with the tabs and settings you want.